# Why are these media queries not overriding each other?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have the following media queries set up in my stylesheet, cna anybody tell me why the bottom query doesn't override the first query?

```
@media screen only and (max-width:992px) {
  .some-element {float:left;}
}

@media screen only and (max-width:768px) {
  .some-element {float:none;}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "only screen" and not "screen only"?

Comment: @BoltClock The OP meant to be float: none not overriding to float: left in 768px

Comment: And I'm suggesting that it might be because the code says "screen only" which is incorrect and preventing either rule from working in the first place.

Comment: yeah, that's true should be answer.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah you're right thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@media screen` instead of `@media screen only`. The bottom query does override the top one.

```css
@media screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .some-element {
        float:left;
        background-color: #f00;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .some-element {
        /** See how the background-color property is overriden */
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="some-element">Hi. I am floating.</div>

<h1>I am a block element</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the media query in the wrong order, the only (or 'not') should come right after the '@media'.
Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
  .some-element {float:left;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .some-element {float:none;}
}
```

Comment: I guess the 'only' means only screen media, ie not print etc?

Comment: yes. It means only screen media-type. 'not' means every but except.